# Xcode 13.2.1 Swift Cannot connect multiple buttons to the same IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to drag different buttons to the same `IBAction` but it’s not working…

The code is opened via `storyboard -> assistant` and I tried to change `UIButton` to `Any` or `AnyObject` but nothing works...

Any help is much appreciated!

```
@IBAction func buttonPressedAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
}
```

update: the attribute inspector

[image]

Comment: Don't bother with the assistant view.  Simply drag from the "touch up inside" to the view controller object in the scene and select your function from the pop up that appears

Answer (score 1):

[image]

try drag from button to code..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I tried this but it does not work either :( The button is not highlighted when I drag on-top of it

Comment: can you share the button attribute inspector properties..? updated my answer check that also.

Comment: I just updated it and I am checking your answer:) Thank you so much!

update: Your properties are really similar to mine... Hmmm..